# Can I simply delete my Ubuntu partition on a windows 10 dual-boot, then reinstall ubuntu from USB, with no windows disk?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I have a bootable USB drive with ubuntu installer. I have Ubuntu and Windows 10 dual booted. I want to start fresh with Ubuntu, so I just want to wipe it totally, and re-install. Everything I need to save is on dropbox anyway. I don't care about messing up Ubuntu, but I don't want to mess up Windows, which I have no disk or activation key for (it's a laptop and windows was pre-installed, so I don't have a key).

Can I just go into windows, delete the ubuntu OS partition (turn it into unassigned space, I suppose?) and the ubuntu storage partition (which is on a separate drive) using windows disk management, and then boot up from the USB stick?

Answer (score 0):

- I would **backup the whole drive** (including Windows) before reinstalling, just in case something would go wrong.

  - You can use Clonezilla, http://clonezilla.org to get an image, that you can use to restore the current dual boot system. If you want to be 100% sure, you should test the backup by restoring to a fresh drive.
  - You can also install Windows from an iso file, if you find a sticker with the license key somewhere on the computer, or if you create 'recovery disks'.
- After that you can **re-install Ubuntu**. You need not remove the old version of Ubuntu, only make sure that you identify the partitions correctly.

  - Select **'Something else'** at the partitioning window of the installer. Select the partitions for the root file system (and other partitions) that you used before and let the installer format them, and continue the installation.